# Node js Verify Crypto Message

Tags: javascript, node.js, cryptojs, verify

I send a request from the client to the server and the server responses back to both the client and the controller with a token. Then, the client receives the token back and sign the token with some extra information (Client IP, time and own blockchain address). After, the client sends the signed information with its own public key. All is good until here.

Now, the controller receives the message with signed information and the public key. Tries to verify this signed information with the coming public key and the message which already has.

Here is Client part code:

```js
  var message = token + "," + client.address().address + "," + time + "," + my_public;
  var message_buf = Buffer.from(message);
  const sign = crypto.createSign('SHA256');
  sign.write(message_buf);
  sign.end();
  const signature = sign.sign(my_private, 'hex');
  var sign_pub = signature.toString() + "," + my_public.toString();
  var sign_pub_buf = Buffer.from(sign_pub);       
  console.log("sign_pub = ", sign_pub_buf);
  client.send(sign_pub_buf, sdn_port, host, function(error){
      if(error){
          client.close();
      }
      else{
          console.log('Sign+Public_K has been sent to SDN  !!!');
      }
```

Here is Controller part code:

```js
udpsocket_sdn.on('message', function(msg, rinfo) {
    console.log('Data received from CLIENT : ' ,msg);
    var sig_pub = msg.toString().split(",");
    var sig = sig_pub[0];
    var pub = sig_pub[1];
    console.log("sig = ", sig);
    console.log("pub = ", pub);
    var message = token + "," + rinfo.address + "," + time + "," + pub;
    var message_buf = Buffer.from(message);
    const verify = crypto.createVerify('SHA256');
    verify.write(message_buf);
    verify.end();
    var isGood = verify.verify(pub, sig, 'hex');
    if(isGood){   
        console.log('All Good');          
    }
    else {
         console.log('Nope !');
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I fixed it. It is working now.

Here is the Client part code:

```js
const { privateKey, publicKey } = crypto.generateKeyPairSync('rsa', {
    modulusLength: 2048,
});
  
var my_public = publicKey.export({type: 'spki', format: 'pem'});
var my_private = privateKey;
var time = 100;


client.on('message',function(msg, info){
    if(data_cnt == 1){
        console.log('Random number received from SERVER !');
        data_cnt++;
        var token_tot = msg.toString().split(",")
        usr1_pub_pem = token_tot[0];
        token = token_tot[1];
        var message = token + "," + ip + "," + time + "," + Buffer.from(my_public);
        console.log("Client address = ", ip)
        const sign = crypto.createSign('SHA256');
        sign.write(message);
        sign.end();
        const signature = sign.sign(my_private, 'hex');      
        client.send(signature, sdn_port, host, function(error){
            if(error){
                client.close();
            }
            else{
                console.log('Signature has been sent to SDN  !!!');     
                client.send(my_public, sdn_port, host, function(error){
                    if(error){
                        client.close();
                    }
                    else{
                        console.log('Public Key has been sent to SDN  !!!');
                    }
                });                              
            }
        });                
    }
});
```

Now, the Controller part :

```js
var time = 100;
udpsocket_sdn.on('message', function(msg, rinfo) {
    count_sdn = count_sdn + 1;
    if(count_sdn == 1){
        console.log('Signature data received from CLIENT !!');
        sig_pub = msg.toString();
    } 
    else if (count_sdn == 2){
        console.log('Public key data received from CLIENT !! ');
        pub = msg;
        var message = token + "," + rinfo.address + "," + time + "," + pub;
        console.log("Client address = ", rinfo.address)
        const verify = crypto.createVerify('SHA256');
        verify.write(message);
        verify.end();
        var isGood = verify.verify(pub, sig_pub, 'hex');
        if(isGood){   
            console.log('All Good');          
        }
        else {
            console.log('Nope !');
        }          
    }
});
```